# Using httpContextAccessor in View via _ViewImports (.net core)

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, .net-core-3.1

I want to use logged in users' informations in all Views. I have a custom class 'CustomUserSM' to serialize/deserialize as claim.

```
public class CustomUserSM
    {
        public bool Authenticated = false;
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public byte userCountryId { get; set; }
        public int userCityId { get; set; }
        etc..
    }
```

I added below lines to _ViewImports

```
@inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor
@inherits ProjectName.Auth.BaseView<TModel>
```

BaseView class is here;

```
public abstract class BaseView<TModel> : RazorPage<TModel>
    {
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
        public readonly CustomUserSM UserInfo;
        public BaseView(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor) 
        {
            _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
            if (_httpContextAccessor != null)
            {
                if (_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Claims.Any(c => c.Type == "Info"))
                {
                    UserInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CustomUserSM>(_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Claims.First(c => c.Type == "Info").Value);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

that line is added to Startup.cs already

```
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

..and i m getting this error;

```
There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'httpContextAccessor' of 'BaseView<dynamic>.BaseView(IHttpContextAccessor)'
```

What i am missing?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding this answer for newbies like me to try dependency injection in a BasePage class which inherits from RazorPage.I was wondering that using httpContext in BasePage (inherits from RazorPage) and injecting something to BasePage.

You can `[RazorInject]` attribute to inject some properties.

```
[RazorInject]
public IHttpContextAccessor _httpContext { get; set; }
```

Ofcourse you have to bind it in Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
            etc..
         }
```

Above is just an example to see how to use it. 
You don't have to inject `IHttpContextAccessor` to access http context because there is already  `public HttpContext Context { get; }` in RazorPage.